# Can I use Microsoft Project to schedule all of my unrelated tasks?

Tags: microsoft-project

What I understand is that each MS Project file is supposed to manage one project. But are there any caveats to using one file to schedule all of my future tasks? For example, can I use one (ever-growing) file to schedule every paving job that I am doing for the next decade, where each paving job may be composed of smaller parts, each of those smaller parts using available resources and materials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. MS-Project does not "know" what a project means to you, it merely manages the scheduling and planning of tasks in a hierarchy. What you are suggesting is no different from a 10-year, multi-client giant Paving Project!

Comment: Great! Do you have an idea if Project starts to get slow when you have a lot of tasks? I think I read you can have up to 400,000, but that doesn't do me any good if it slows down at 50,000. Thanks!

Comment: No idea @Mike, I've only ever used up to about a thousand for my most complex projects. Any more than that and you may have a planning problem as things rarely need to be planned in such detail- Or to put it another way, planning something in such detail bears so little resemblance to reality that it becomes a pointless exercise. I am sure there are exceptions to this, but they would be supermassive projects IMO. YMMV